# Regex positive lookbehind with OR operator

Tags: javascript, regex

My test string are following

```
2s, 5s
2s, 5.5s
```

I am trying to write a regex that matches any integer or decimal after `,`

I can separately write

```
(?<=\, )\d\.\d
```

which would return `5.5`

or write

```
(?<=\, )\d
```

which would return `5`

How can I combine both of them?

I tried this which does not work

```
(?<=\, )\d||\d\.\d
```

Comment: Use `(?<=, )\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: Even this if space is optional `(?<=,[ ]*)(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/TP5okI/1 My answers are never Duplicates of anything.